# Align the start of the text in EditText and TextVIew

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple layout in a table that consists of 3 rows. The second column may have either an EditText or a TextView like in the picture below:

[image]

Now, my question is how can I align the start of the text in EditText and TextView so that they are visually under each other (the texts, not the controls)? In the image above, the text in the second line starts too much to the left. I don't want to hardcode the padding as it may not work the same way on different devices.

Comment: 1 - you can use Relative layout with align property
2 - Can use manually margin
3 - Can use padding as well

But (1) is best as compare to other.

Comment: But how do I align to the start of the text in EditText?

Comment: You can set padding of Edittext

Comment: But that will move the whole EditText. The problem is that the text in EditText starts after a small amount of gap.

Comment: No, Its move the text inside the edittext. Please try

Comment: set this properties style="@android:style/Widget.EditText" to TextView so it's look like EditText

Comment: Amit, that worked :) You lead me to the solution. If you put it as the answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting a padding for the second textview.

```
android:padding="5dp"
```

Comment: or you can set the Leftmargin of the "Simple past" to about 5dp

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the TextView match the EditText, make the EditText match the TextView by making its background null:

```
<EditText ... android:background="@null" ... />
```

The underline in the EditText then goes away and everything lines up perfectly.